# Keras overfitting and underfitting

Tags: keras, neural-network, deep-learning

I know there are so many discussion about this.
I knew overfitting and underfitting from this image.
[image: overfitting and underfitting]

image from : https://www.kaggle.com/dansbecker/underfitting-and-overfitting

But how about this?

[image]

validation loss stucks.

Does this mean underfitting?

Answer (score 2):

That's an even worse case of overfitting, as the validation doens't improve at all while the training error keeps going down. It may be that the training set is not representative of the validation and test data. This question should be in CrossValidated.